# how to hide information schema in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to hide all the details (table structure, database design etc). How do I do that, I searched in Google and got some information.

From that, I have changed the contents of config.inc.php:

```
<?php

 /* Servers configuration */
 $i = 0;

 /* Server: localhost [1] */
 $i++;
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema';

 /* End of servers configuration */

 $cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
 $cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
 $cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
 $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';


?>
```

but still, when I go to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=mysql&token=df40bf81f38ce55621e179517c212d62
```

I can see all the information.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *already* hidden. The reason why it's available is because:

- You have *no* **root** password.
- You haven't logged out of your session, therefore the cookie that contains your session information is validated and you're automatically redirected to the information (DBs, tables). This is to avoid logging in every time you refresh.

Also, check out the "allownopassword" entry, if it's set to true it allows people with no password to log in. Try setting it to false.

Set the root password in MySQL (and as far as the root password variable.. I ***highly*** recommend not putting the password in the php file.)

If you have never set a root password for MySQL server, the server allows you to identify as root without a password. To make a root password, type this in the shell:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD



<?php

 /* Servers configuration */
 $i = 0;

 /* Server: localhost [1] */
 $i++;
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // If you're going to use ROOT for ALL WORK, set a root password and put it below.
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'PASSWORD';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false; // False!
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema';

 /* End of servers configuration */

 $cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
 $cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
 $cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
 $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';


?>
```

By the way, config does not password protect phpMyAdmin; anyone who accesses the correct URL is logged directly in and can manipulate your server.

Make an .htaccess file to prevent this!

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from YourIPAddress
```

Comment: Thanks, also, add the .htaccess!

Answer (score 0):

Edit config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|test$'; 
if(in_array($_GET['db'], array('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'test'))) {
    exit;
}
```